# C++ disabled copy constructor, can't create object

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I do not provide any custom constructors for my class, all I did was disable the copy constructor:

```
private:
MyClass(const MyClass& other) = delete; // disable copy ctor
```

Now, when I try to create an instance of this class on the stack

```
MyClass myInstance;
```

I get a compilation error like this:

```
main.cpp:16:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass()’
```

It's as if I've inadvertently disabled the default constructor? Or perhaps the copy constructor is getting called there, I just don't see how.

Here is an example

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int someField;

private:
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) = delete; // disable copy ctor
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass other) = delete; // disable assignment

};
```

And the error

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"proj/main.d" -MT"pitch/main.o" -o "proj/main.o" "../proj/main.cpp"
../proj/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../proj/main.cpp:17:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass()’
  MyClass ins;
```

Comment: I just have a reproducible example. Also no idea why the downvotes, tried to asked some C++ questions earlier today, everyone was super mean.

Comment: Declaring constructors disables the default constructor. Never tested to see if that also happens with the copy constructor, but looks like.

Comment: See [deleted implicitly declared default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_default_constructor). Also see [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Adding a `MyClass () = default;` should fix it up.

Comment: You don't have default constructor, this is what the error tells you

Comment: But isn't the default constructor created by default? Why did deleting the copy constructor also eliminate the default constructor?

Comment: default constructor is created by default **unless** you decide to create or delete any other constructors, then you must explicitly state which constructor you want to keep

Comment: Because of rule of 5. If you need to manually define a copy constructor the default constructor generated by the compiler will most likely be wrong and therefore not generated. Essentially the same goes for the other 5 special member functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have a default constructor, hence the error:

> ../proj/main.cpp:17:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass()’

You may be confused, because before you declared your disabled copy constructor your code worked fine. This is because the [compiler will generate a default constructor for any class without a constructor already declared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

> If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor

You need to declare a default constructor. Reading on from the above link (and as [hinted to by @user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553881/c-disabled-copy-constructor-cant-create-object#comment84104234_48553881)):

> If some user-declared constructors are present, the user may still force the automatic generation of a default constructor by the compiler that would be implicitly-declared otherwise with the keyword default.

This can be done like so:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() = default;
    int someField;
```

Comment: I see. So even though I did not really implement a copy constructor, but simply deleted it, this interference on my part was enough for the compiler to not want to create default constructor any more?

Comment: @BaronYugovich to be precise you __declared__ it deleted.  When you start saying the class has special (unusual) behaviour then the compiler bails and requires you to tell it what to do with the member functions it implements by default.